# Get Mailbox Name Of Current Active (Or Open) Email

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2013

I have existing VBA code that performs some tasks on a selected email. This is ok. I have two mailboxes in Outlook 2013.

What I need to determine when I execute the VBA code is which mailbox the selected email is from; Mailbox1 or Mailbox2.

Answer (score 3):

Use `MailItem.Parent` (returns `MAPIFolder` object), then use `MAPIFolder.Store.Name` to figure out the name of the current store.

If you actually need to figure out the address of the store's owner, you will need to use Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi only) or [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) - use [RDOExchangeMailboxStore](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdostore.htm#RDOExchangeMailboxStore).`Owner.Name`.

Comment: Thank you for the input. I adapted my code and the macro works perfect. Cheers